# Error registering IErrorHandler with Rebus

Tags: rebus

Error below occurred:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=A
>   circular dependency was detected for the service of type
>   'Rebus.Retry.IErrorHandler'.
>   Rebus.Retry.IErrorHandler(Rebus.AzureServiceBus.ErrorMessage.ErrorMessageHandler)
>   -> Rebus.Retry.IErrorHandler   Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain.CheckCircularDependency(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type
>   serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   RebusSubscriber.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.b__5(IResolutionContext
>   c) in C:_Repos\AzureServiceBus\Subscriber\RebusSubscriber.cs:line 45
>   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.GetTService

Below registers dependency for `IErrorHandler`

```
services.AddTransient<IErrorHandler, ErrorMessageHandler>();
```

Below is how it resolves `ErrorMessageHandler` and error above occurred.

```
Configure.With(Activator)
                .Options(o =>
                {                   
                    o.Decorate<IErrorHandler>(c => 
new ErrorMessageHandler(c.Get<IErrorHandler>()));
                    }



public class ErrorMessageHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        private readonly IErrorHandler _errorHandler;

        public ErrorMessageHandler(IErrorHandler errorHandler)
        {
            _errorHandler = errorHandler;
        } 

        public async Task HandlePoisonMessage(TransportMessage transportMessage, ITransactionContext transactionContext, Exception exception)
        {
            // keep original behaviour
            await _errorHandler.HandlePoisonMessage(transportMessage, transactionContext, exception);
        }
    }
```

It seems not using IResolutionContext causes the error.

Is there a solution?

**Update**

The problem is that `IResolutionContext` is required to register its own implementation instead of own IoC. It seems the name of `IErrorHandler` is overused.

My requirement is, given two separate components (Rebus wrapper, and its client), that we need to let client of rebus wrapper to define and use custom error handler, `ErrorMessageHandler` in this case.

For example, the pseudocode of Rebus wrapper below:

```
Configure.With(Activator)
                    .Options(o =>
                    {                   

//logic to implement below that allow different message handler somehow
//ErrorMessageHandler is this case.
                        o.Decorate<IErrorHandler>(c => 
           xxxxxxx(c.Get<IErrorHandler>()));
                        }
```

Pseudocode of Client of the Rebus wrapper:

```
 //pass ErrorMessageHandler to the Rebus wrapper above.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the Microsoft Dependency Injection container – it's caused by the fact that your `IErrorHandler` implementation takes an `IErrorHandler` in its constructor, which it doesn't seem to like.

This particular pattern is the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which helps transparently extend the capabilities of existing services. Rebus encourages you to use it to extend its behavior, which you seem to be doing correctly by registering it with `configurer.Decorate<IErrorHandler>(...)`.

The error in this case seems to be that you're registering your `ErrorMessageHandler` in your IoC container. Rebus doesn't use your IoC container to resolve its own services, it's ONLY used for resolving message handlers.

Your `IErrorHandler` is not a message handler, it's the abstraction that decides how Rebus deals with messages once they have failed too many times.

Therefore: Don't register it in your IoC container.